# How to separate numbers from letters in text of list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a `list[]` which contains phrases like `list = ['123Abc','234Asx','456Aio','...']`.I would like to separate numbers from letters. The recurrent model is 3 numbers followed by capital A. How can I do that? I tried many ways using `list.replace` but I don't know how to set it, or whether the existence or not of a better method to use.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: the output should be `['123 Abc','234 Asx','456 Aio','...']`. So I don't want to be separated into 2 different lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get continuous groups of items, using a function to determine to what group each item belongs, use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). In your case, you (presumably) want continuous sets of digits and non-digits, so the `key` is [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdigit#str.isdigit), applied to each of the characters in your input string.

The number of digits can be variable, the letter-part does not need to start with `A`, and you actually can have *any* series of digits and letters in *any* order: `groupby` will sort it out.

The result of `groupby` is an *iterator* (so you must convert it to something definitive such as a list), in the format "`key` result, group object". You can see the `isdigit` fired correctly for all characters by printing out the immediate result:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['123Abc','234Asx','456Aio']
print ([(i,list(j)) for i,j in groupby (l[0], key=lambda x:x[0].isdigit())])
```

which is

```
[(True, ['1', '2', '3']), (False, ['A', 'b', 'c'])]
```

Converting the `list(j)` back to a single string only needs a `join`. You don't want to know *whether* you have a list of digits or not, so you can discard the boolean result and store only the strings. This

```
print ([''.join(j) for i,j in groupby (l[0], key=lambda x:x[0].isdigit())])
```

yields

```
['123', 'Abc']
```

for the first item in your list, and if your desired result is a list for every item in your current list, add an iteration around this one:

```
print ([[''.join(j) for i,j in groupby (item, key=lambda x:x[0].isdigit())] for item in l])
```

returns

```
[['123', 'Abc'], ['234', 'Asx'], ['456', 'Aio']]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension and add a space at position 3 in each string:

```
[e[:3] + ' ' + e[3:] for e in my_list]
```

output:

```
['123 Abc', '234 Asx', '456 Aio', '... ']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [int(val[:3]) for val in list]
text = [val[3:] for val in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
text = ['A'+i.split('A')[1] for i in list]
numbers = [i.split('A')[0] for i in list]
```

output:

```
['Abc', 'Asx', 'Aio']
['123', '234', '456']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it to get the result you want. This is done using `re.findall` and is independent of the scenario where the separating character is 'A'.

```
import re

test_list = ['123Abc','234Asx','456Aio']

result = [' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+', x)) for x in test_list]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['123 Abc', '234 Asx', '456 Aio']
```

Time taken to run:

`3.62 µs ± 13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

This seems to run faster than the accepted solution. From my analysis, the accepted solution runs in approximately:

`5.79 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`